# What's the simplest way to encode a chosen 'root' Core Data entity together with all of its relationships?

Tags: ios, core-data, decode, encode

I use Core Data within my iOS 7 app to handle the editing and creation of entities. The entities have relationships between them, which all have inverses (as Apple advises).

For the sake of this question, let's pick any one of these interrelated entities and call it the `Root` entity: the thing that I want to encode with; the thing that logically lives on the 'top' of the hierarchy. I will call this the 'object graph'.

The question is:

**What's the easiest way of encoding and decoding such an object graph to and from NSData?**

The reason I want to do this is that I'd like my Core Data object graph to be persisted onto a cloud service, without the need of writing my own `NSIncrementalStore` subclass (it's a bit involved...!).

[AutoCoding](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AutoCoding) together with [HRCoder](https://github.com/nicklockwood/HRCoder) *almost* looks like it could do the job, but I've experimented with this combination and it doesn't quite work with `NSManagedObjects` at the time of writing.

Still, I'm seeking alternatives. There can't only be one way to do this, surely.

It doesn't have to be JSON, but it'd be nice. Binary would be fine.

Comment: RestKit? Do you actually have a web service?

Comment: No, I use Parse at the moment. So I could either use REST or Parse's own SDK. I prefer to use the SDK to upload some arbitrary `NSData`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you do not need to subclass `NSIncrementalStore`. You can create records and save them to your store with a plain vanilla store created via `addPersistentStoreWithType:...` with a `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

The straight-forward way is to handle the incoming JSON by simply taking the data and copying it to the properties of your `NSManagedObject` subclasses, like this:

```
object.title = jsonDictionary[@"title"];
object.numericAttribute = [jsonDictionary[@"numericAttribute] integerValue];
```

If you take care about naming the attribute and entity names exactly the same you can maybe use some shortcuts using KVC, like

```
[object setValue:jsonDictionary[key] forKey:key];
```

I once did the above for a large legacy project where it was not feasible to repeat the old attribute names, so I used a custom property list (plist) to match around 800 attribute names.